# How to Copy paste a cell Value, if Cell contain more than 0 then paste to another cell by loop

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need to copy **C74** Cell

Then Paste to **C85 to C88**

Condition1: Which Cell have More than 0 no need to paste

Condition2: Which Cell have 0, then Paste the C74 Value.

*No need to paste to all cells that have 0's

*Just paste Value to first cell that is contain 0.

I try it For upto 2 cell.
But I need it For upto 4 cell.

Anyone guide me..

```
Sub TIMECALC()
ActiveSheet.Range("C74").Copy
If ActiveSheet.Range("C85").Value > 0 Then ActiveSheet.Range("C86").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False Else ActiveSheet.Range("C85").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Snap

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `For Each...` to loop through the range `C85:C88`, do the comparison if the value of those cells are greater than 0. Then paste the content/value of C74 if true.

```
Sub Calc()

    'Copy the cell
    Range("C74").Copy
    'Loop through each cell of the range
    For Each cell In Range("C85:C88")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            'Paste copied value
            cell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            'Exit the loop
            Exit For
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This One paste Entire Cells that have 0, But i need to paste the value one by one when i re run the macro.

 For example First time paste to in cell C85, then C85 have value, then paste to C86, like this manner need to paste sequence

Comment: Here I need to Sum C74 value, For each macro run.  Because Every time the value changed. My idea is copy paste the C74 value to Paste one by one then sum it to calculate total.

Comment: @baskar See edit. I have added "Exit For" to the code. The loop will be stopped after pasting C74 value to the first cell that is equals to 0.